# How do I import a CSV file into CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a CSV file I exported from a MySQL database and I want to move it over to CockroachDB. How do I read in the data from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

#### CockroachDB v2.0 or later

CSV import is natively supported in CockroachDB 2.0 and later using the `IMPORT` statement. You can specify a custom delimiter using the `WITH delimiter` option, as shown in [these examples](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/import.html#examples) and [this migration guide](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/migrate-from-csv.html#column-delimiter).

For example:

```
IMPORT TABLE customers
    CREATE USING 'azure://acme-co/customer-create-table.sql'
    CSV DATA ('azure://acme-co/customer-import-data.csv')
```

In v2.1, you can also import directly from a MySQL or PostgreSQL file using `IMPORT MYSQLDUMP` or `IMPORT PGDUMP`. See [this section](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/import.html#import-a-postgres-database-dump) of the docs, as well as the [MySQL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/migrate-from-mysql.html)/[Postgres](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/migrate-from-postgres.html) migration guides, for more details.

#### CockroachDB v1.1 or earlier

The easiest way to get a CSV file into CockroachDB is to use a CSV to SQL converter that turns each row in your CSV into a SQL `INSERT` statement. You can find any number of websites that will do this for you, or you can build a script to do the processing in something like awk, Perl or Python. Once you've got your SQL `INSERT` statements in a file, you can execute them like so:

```
cockroach sql --database=[your db] < [file].sql
```

Alternatively, if you have Postgres installed, you can connect to CockroachDB through `psql` and use its `COPY` command to import the CSV.

```
psql postgres://USER@HOST:PORT/DATABASE -c "COPY [table] FROM '[path to].csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
```

If you're running CockroachDB on the default port on your local machine, here's the same command with the defaults filled in:

```
psql postgres://root@localhost:26257/DATABASE -c "COPY [table] FROM '[path to].csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
```

Comment: the postgres copy command load to cockroach didnt work for me. This approach is not mentioned in documentation as well, so I am assuming its not really supported. pgdump restores are supported though.

Comment: This doesn't work as of 2.1 because CockroachDB does not support `DELIMITER` in the syntax and thus cannot accept a CSV file with comma delimiters.

Comment: @RKKuppala @ManiGandham you must use `psql` (i.e., the Postgres CLI), not `cockroach sql`, in order to use the COPY commands.

Answer (score 2):

Cockroach doesn't support the `DELIMITER` statement it also does not accepts the `CSV` format explicit so the right command in order to use `COPY FROM` would be:

`psql postgres://user@host:port/DATABASE -c "COPY [table] FROM '[path to].csv';"`

The delimiter character **must** be the special character `\t` so if your CSV file is using `,` as delimiter, you can convert it easily using sed:

`sed -i 's/,/\t/g' [your file].csv`

Why they hardcoded the special character `\t` as delimiter instead of `,` is beyond my knowledge.

There is already an open issue about this in https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/16407

Answer (score 0):

The above instructions are now outdated; CSV import is natively supported in CockroachDB 2.0 and later using the `IMPORT` statement. You can specify a custom delimiter using the `WITH delimiter` option, as shown in [these examples](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/import.html#examples) and [this migration guide](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/migrate-from-csv.html#column-delimiter).

If you're using CockroachDB 2.1 and migrating from MySQL or Postgres, you can also import directly from a mysqldump or pg_dump SQL file using `IMPORT MYSQLDUMP` or `IMPORT PGDUMP`. See [this section](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/import.html#import-a-postgres-database-dump) of the docs, as well as the [MySQL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/migrate-from-mysql.html)/[Postgres](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/migrate-from-postgres.html) migration guides, for more details.